# InputFilter 's subclasses NumberKeyListener, DigitsKeyListener, ... strange behavior

Tags: android

What is expected:

The code:

```
    EditText textET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textET);
    textET.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DigitsKeyListener()});
```

where textET in main_layout.xml is defined as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textET"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

should produce editable text field that filters characters and allows only digits. 
But when some alphabetic characters are clicked on soft keyboard and then entered some digits the following happens:
First entered digit is displayed as expected. Next entered digit repeats previous and prints itself. Next repeats previous sequence and prints itself. Etc.

For example:

First try to enter alphabetic characters. Nothing is displayed. It is ok.

Then '2' is clicked - '2' is displayed. It's ok.

Then '5' is clicked - '225' is displayed. '25' is expected.

Then '8' is clicked - '225258' is displayed. '258' is expected.

And so on.

Besides when last character is been tried to delete by 'Backspace' it's not deleted but new previous sequence is appended. In example: '225258' > 'Backspace' prints '225258225258'

Am i doing or expecting something wrong? Or is that a glitch?

(Code as simple as posted here. Tested on Galaxy S2, API 4.1 . Emulator works as expected.)

Comment: Indeed a weird behavior..  maybe only allowing numbers in the EditText in xml helps? `android:inputType="number"`

Answer (score 0):

This problem from keyboard helper in android. You shouldn't use filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    textET.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
            // Maximum 2 characters.
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter( 2 ),
            // Digits only.
            DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(),  
    });
```